# Distance from a state of a $C^*$-algebra to the state space

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Suppose $\tau$ is a state of a $C^*$-algebra $A$ and $S$ is a $\sigma(A^*, A)$ closed subspace of the state space $S(A)$. The disance forom $\tau$ to $S$ is defined as following:

$d(\tau, S)=inf_{\phi\in S(A)}\|\tau-\phi\|$.

Does there exist $\phi \in S(A)$ such that  $d(\tau,\phi)=d(\tau , S)$? Is the norm on the dual of $A$ lower semi-continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only answer for the separable and unital case. Under these conditions $S(A)$ is weak-* closed (because $A$ is unital), so $S$ is also weak-* closed in $A^*$, so $S$ is weak-* compact by Banach Alaoglu. Since $A$ is separable, the closed unit ball of $A$ endowed with the weak-* topology is metrizable. So $S$ endowed with the weak-* topology is homeomorphic to a compact metric space. We define $f:S\to[0,\infty)$ by $f(\phi)=\|\tau-\phi\|$. If we prove that $f$ is lower semi-continuous with respect to the weak-* topology, then since lower semi-continuous functions over compact metric spaces attain their minimum, we will have that there exists $\phi\in S$ so that $\|\tau-\phi\|=d(\tau,S)$.

Let $\phi_i\to\phi$ in $S$ in the weak-* topology. Then $\tau-\phi_i\to \tau-\phi$ in $A^*$ with the weak-* topology. It suffices to show that the norm is lower semi-continuous with respect to the weak-* topology on $A^*$. So let $\psi_i\to\psi$ in $A^*$. If $\varepsilon>0$, then we may find a unit element $a\in A$ so that $\|\psi\|\leq|\psi(a)|+\varepsilon$. Since $\psi_i(a)\to\psi(a)$, we find $i_o\in I$ such that for all $i\geq i_o$ we have $|\psi(a)-\psi_i(a)|<\varepsilon$. But then

$$\|\psi\|\leq|\psi(a)|+\varepsilon\leq|\psi_i(a)|+2\varepsilon\leq\|\psi_i\|+2\varepsilon$$
for all $i\geq i_o$. So the function is lower semi continuous.

Comment: I am not sure if lower semi-continuous functions attain their minima over arbitrary compact topological ($T_2$) spaces, so the separability assumption can be dropped. If anybody knows, please feel free to edit/comment.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but in your second paragraph, you don't show that the norm is weak$^*$-continuous on $A^*$, contrary to what you state in the third sentence of this paragraph.  And indeed this is false:  if $A=C_0(\mathbb R)$, $\phi_x(f)=f(x)$, then $\phi_x\to 0$ weak$^*$ as $x\to \infty$, while $\|\phi_x\|=1$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Aweygan  Woops. Sorry, I started by trying to prove that the norm is continuous, then I saw that it probably isn't but I realized lower semi continuity suffices so I went for that.  Thanks for noticing, I will edit. Do you agree with the rest of my proof though?

Comment: @mathbeginner If $\psi_i$ is a net in that set and $\psi_i\to \psi$ then I prove that $\|\psi\|\leq a+2\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon>0$, so $\|\psi\|\leq a$ and the set is closed. What I am proving is equivalent to the definition, this is an easy result

Comment: @mathbeginner You have mixed things up. I am talking about the arbitrary $\alpha$ of your comment, not the elemet $a\in A$ in my proof. I just used $a$ instead of $\alpha$. Read my answer and my comment carefully, it is a solid proof.

Comment: Would you mind proving it by using another definition? For any $\alpha$, how to prove  $\{x\in S:f(x)\leq \alpha\} $ is closed?

Comment: @mathbeginner I just explained that in the comment! Take $\psi_i$ a net in the set $\{\phi\in S(A): \|\phi\|\leq\alpha\}$ and suppose that $\psi_i\to\psi$ in weak-*. Then find a vector $a\in A$ such that $\|\psi\|\leq|\psi(a)|+\varepsilon$. Then since $\psi_i(a)\to\psi(a)$ we have that $\|\psi\|\leq |\psi_i(a)|+2\varepsilon\leq \|\psi_i\|+2\varepsilon$ for all $i$ after a certain index. But then $\|\psi\|\leq\alpha+2\varepsilon$. since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, we have $\|\psi\|\leq\alpha$.

Comment: I have another question: You menioned $S(A)$ is weak*-closed, how to prove it ? If $\{x_n\}\subset S(A)$ coverges to $x$ in weak$*$-topology, then $\|x_n(a)–x(a)\|\to 0$ for any $a\in A$. I cannot check that $x\in S(A)$.

Comment: @mathbeginner If $A$ is unital, then a bounded functional $\phi$ is positive if and only if $\phi(1_A)=\|\phi\|$. Now if $(x_n)\subset S(A)$ and $x_n\to x$ in the weak-* topology, we have that $x(1_A)=\lim_{n}x_n(1_A)=\lim_n\|x_n\|=1$. Now we have that $\|x\|\geq|x(1_A)|=1$ and it is easy to see that $\|x\|\leq1$.